# Phone Number REX python/javascript validation

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I create a regular expression but one type of number is not acceptable.
https://jsfiddle.net/ofn9knay/1/

```
Result for 9820098200 false
Result for 9820098200#301 false
Result for +919820098200 false
Result for +91-982-009-8200 false
Result for +1 (866) 582-2655 true
Result for +91 444 741 4000 true
Result for (+91-66) 6852 3522 false
```

But it not accepting the `(+91-79) 6652 3952`

REGEX which I used is:

```
/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/
```

Comment: Post your regex in question, you can move also that code to SO snippet (`[<>]` icon in editor)

Comment: @ barbsan, can you please  have a look at edited one.

Comment: You have only one `\d` group that accepts 4 digits and it won't match also that prefix in bracket

Comment: so can you please tell me the solution. if possible.

Comment: Please don't just show the results you get from the regex, but tell us what number formats the regex SHOULD accept and what number formats SHOULD  be rejected. To me it is totally unclear why `(+91-79) 6652 3952` is acceptable and why `+91-982-009-8200` is not..

Answer (score 0):

If you figure out what beginning string will be, so regex will be easier than you thought. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/70V8m3/2)

```
(.\d+|\(.\d+-\d+\))(\s\d{1,4})+
```